# It is some kind of OpenGL in TCL, but what language is this?

Tags: opengl, tcl

This is `TCL` and `OpenGL`, but I don't know which language it exactly is, and so cannot find the documentation for it. In particular, I need to understand all the attributes on the OGL line.

```
global Qu

gl matrixmode projection
gl pushmatrix
gl loadidentity

gl ortho 0 50. 0 50. -1. 1.
gl matrixmode modelview
gl pushmatrix
gl loadidentity

gl color 1 1 1 1
if {$Qu(Speed) >= 30 } { 
    OGL drawtex sans-bold "Speed 3" -center -pos 25 47 0 -dir 2 0 0 -up 0 2 0
    OGL drawtex sans "[format %#.3g $Qu(Speed)]" -center -pos 25 44 0 -dir 3 0 0 -up 0 3 0
}
```

The function of this code is to display the speed as two lines of text on screen, when `speed>=30`.

Comment: Actually i think it should be easy to find information about this. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @FelixK. thanks for your advice. I was searching answers for days before I post the question here today. And of course I will keep on searching. :)

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford Thank you very much for editing the question. I really appreciate it! Have a nice day. :)

Comment: You probably have some `package require` in your script to load the library providing the `OGL` and `gl` commands to your interpreter. Finding it should give a hint where the docs will be.

Comment: @schlenk thanks for your idea. You got the key. Those codes i am working on is just a part of the whole program. They will be called as a function from the main program, which is close-sourced. That means i have no idea which package/library they are using. T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first lines from `gl matrixmode projection` to `gl color 1 1 1 1` are pretty easy OpenGL functions ( *deprecated OpenGL actually* ). The other line seems self explaining, however you can try to change them slightly to see what effects each parameter has.

I think its as follow ( Only a guess ):

- *OGL drawtext*: Command for drawing a text
- *sans-bold*: Font family or file name.
- *"Speed 3"*: Simple text
- *"[format %#.3g $Qu(Speed)]"*: Formatted text which inserts the speed into the string.
- *-center*: Text is centered around it's position.
- *-pos*, *-dir* and *-up*: Position, direction and up vector

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have some how tried to modify those codes, and they work just as your guess. The "UP VECTOR" idea from you is just brilliant. Thanks!